# How to make dynamic dependent dorpdown lists in Symfony using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I tried to make depend dropdown lists in Symfony using Ajax call, when I enter in the specified URL it shows the result I want (array of elements) see the picture [image: url]

The result is correct but nothing is showing in the dropdown list, what I'm doing wrong ?
here it is the Form:

```
 <form method="GET" class="search-jobs-form" id="form" 
             name="form">
          <div class="row mb-5">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 mb-4 
            mb-lg-0">
              <select class="selectpicker dynamic" data-dependent="element" name="category" id="category" data-style="btn-white btn-lg" data-width="100%" data-live-search="true" title="Séléctionner une catégorie">
                {% for category in categories %}     
                <option>{{category}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
              </select> 

             </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
              <select class="selectpicker" name="element" id="element" 
              data-style="btn-white btn-lg" data-width="100%"
               data-live-search="true">
             <option value="">Select Element</option>
              </select>
            </div>
           </div>
         </from>
```

The controller function:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use App\Entity\Element;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

     class ListController extends AbstractController
        {

      /**
      * @Route("/site/list", name="site.list", methods={"GET","POST"})
    */
   public function getChild(Request $request)
      {


   $slct = $request->query->get('select');

   $val = $request->query->get('value');

   $dpnt =$request->query->get('dependent');

   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
   $q= $em->createQuery(
             "SELECT ce
             FROM App\Entity\CategoryElements ce WHERE ce.category=:val"
        );
        $q->setParameter('val', $val);
        $data=$q->getResult();


              foreach($data as $row)
              {
               $output[] = $row->$dpnt;
             }

             return new JsonResponse($output);


            }
         }
```

And the Ajax call in Twig file:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#category').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        var select = $(this).attr("id");
        console.log(select);
        var value = $(this).val();
        console.log(value);
        var dependent = $(this).data('dependent');
        console.log(dependent);
        var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'site/list',
            method: "GET",
            data: { select: select, value: value, _token: _token, dependent: dependent },
            success: function(data) {
                var htmlOptions = [];
       if( data.length ){
          for( item in data ) {
              html = '<option value="' + data[item] + '">' + data[item] + '</option>';
          htmlOptions[htmlOptions.length] = html;
          }


           $("#element").empty().append( htmlOptions.join('') );
      }
                }

        })
    }
});


 })(jQuery);
```

Comment: you don't need to do many javascript nor loops just with "replaceWith", there is a good example in the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Answer (score 0):

I think , you will never get selected value with `$(this).val();` so your ajax code never fired.

Try this for your js code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#category').change(function() {
        if ($(this).children("option:selected").val()) {
            var select = $(this).attr("id");
            var value = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
            var dependent = $(this).data('dependent');
            var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/site/list', // <- change your url to this
                method: "GET",
                data: { select: select, value: value, _token: _token, dependent: dependent },
                success: function(data) {
                    var htmlOptions = '';

                    if( data.length ){
                        htmlOptions = '';
                        $(data).each(function (item,value) {
                            htmlOptions += '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>'
                        });

                        // here you will empty the pre-existing data from you selectbox and will append the
                        // htmlOption created in the loop result
                        $("#element").empty().append( htmlOptions );
                    }
                }

            })
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm  getting the same result, actually I'm getting the value as I said so when trying "console.log(data)" it shows the result I want but I don't know why it's not getting this result to populate the dropdown menu